# Web application spring boot and angular 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am making a simple CRUD application using Spring boot and MongoDB, the problem that I am facing is that I don't know how to define the model classes.

My application should be like this:

A site has some characteristics such as an ID, region, city, ... and contains 4 parts (cellulars) that each has its own characteristics. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Site {

    @Id
    String siteId;
    String projectPhase;
    String region;
    String city;
    String siteName;
    String newSiteName;
    String clusterName ;
    String longitude ;
    String lattitude ;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "siteId")
    List  L;
```

What I want to know is how do I associate another class inside this one.

Comment: The question appears to be about ORM/JPA (used by Spring Boot), and not about typescript, or mongo, or angular5. Also, it is unclear what you have tried, and what other class you want to associate. Provide more details about your exact problem; as the question stands, it cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations like `@OneToMany` are typically used within JPA-context, and are unnecessary when using Spring Data MongoDB. This is also mentioned by [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references):

> There’s no need to use something like `@OneToMany` because the mapping framework sees that you want a one-to-many relationship because there is a `List` of objects.

You have a few options when you want to define one-to-many relations when using MongoDB. The first of them is to define them as embedded objects within the same document:

```
@Document
public class Site {
     @Id
     private String id;
     private String city;
     private String region;
     private List<Part> cellulars;
}

public class Part {
    private String characteristic1;
    private String characteristic2;
}
```

This means that the parts do not exist on their own, so they don't need their own ID either.

Another possibility is to reference to another document:

```
@Document
public class Site {
     @Id
     private String id;
     private String city;
     private String region;
     @DBRef
     private List<Part> cellulars;
}

@Document
public class Part {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String characteristic1;
    private String characteristic2;
}
```

In this case, parts are also separate documents, and a site simply contains a reference to the part.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, this is very helpful.